# if else statement using ".isEmpty" not working (swift3)

Tags: ios, if-statement, swift3, textfield, is-empty

I have a textfield that stores a date using date picker. I have a textview that I would like to remain hidden until date is selected. To this i have the following code.

```
     import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var thetextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label.isHidden = thetextField.text!.isEmpty
     }
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    label.isHidden = textField.text!.isEmpty
}}
```

Comment: The code runs once in `viewDidLoad`. You need to run the code always when the `text` property is changed.

Comment: I tried the same thing in viewDidAppear it did not work

Comment: Does the text property of `dptext` change in `viewDidAppear`? Certainly not. Once again, you have to run the code always after each occurrence of `dptext.text = ....`

Comment: **Do not call system delegate methods by yourself**. You can write the check in one line: `label.isHidden = thetextField.text!.isEmpty`. Put the line in both `viewDidLoad` and `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

Comment: I dont understand where I put label.isHidden = thetextField.text!.isEmpty in textFieldDidEndEditing.

Comment: @vadian I dont understand where I put label.isHidden = thetextField.text!.isEmpty in textFieldDidEndEditing. –

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are only checking the `isEmpty` property once. What you need instead is to check this property in a `delegate` method of `textField`

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.text.isEmpty {
        enterName.isHidden = true
    } else {
        enterName.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Your code will look like this

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var thetextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label.isHidden = thetextField.text!.isEmpty
        thetextField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        label.isHidden = textField.text!.isEmpty
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to call that function in viewdidload. I edited my question with your suggested answer. The label is hidden when it loads however when text is entered the label is still hidden with they way I tried to call the function.

Comment: You need to read up on `delegates` and how to use them. They will help you a lot in the long run. Once you understand delegates, you can look into `UITextField` delegates on Apple's website. Here is the link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate

Comment: do I need to put anything in viewdidload for your code to work.

Comment: Yes. you can setup your textField's delegate in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: is label.isHidden = textField.text!.isEmpty the "textField" part the "thetextField" or "textField".

Comment: Sorry about that. `thetextField` in `viewDidLoad` and either option in the `delegate` method. See updated answer

Comment: i tried your code above, when text is entered in the textfield, the label still does not appear.

Comment: Make sure the `IBOutlet` is properly hooked up. Also, ensure you have added `UITextFieldDelegate` at the top